# Does Matcher show the location of the Regex Match?

Tags: java, regex, adif

I have a file format that I'm working on parsing, called the ADIF format. It might look something like this:

```
<BAND:3>15M   <MODE:4>JT65
```

There are 2 pieces of information that I need to retrieve from this, for each set. The tag, which is inside the <>'s, and the data, which is outside. The number after the : indicates the number of characters to read after the `>`.

I'm trying to do this via a regex, using something that looks like this:

```
String tag=m.group();
String tagName=(String) tag.subSequence(1,tag.length()-1);
int cI=tag.indexOf(':');
String data="";
if (cI!=-1) {
    tagName=(String) tag.subSequence(1,cI);
    int numChar=Integer.parseInt((String) tag.subSequence(cI+1,tag.length()-1));
    int end=m.regionEnd()+1;
    data = (String) line.subSequence(end,end+numChar-1);
}
```

The problem is that the Region as defined by the Matcher covers the entire line. Is there a way to find the characters where the match occurs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured this out right after posting... Sigh.

Use the `end()` function, instead of `regionEnd()`

```
int end=m.end();
```

So that makes the final code:

```
String tag=m.group();
String tagName=(String) tag.subSequence(1,tag.length()-1);
int cI=tag.indexOf(':');
String data="";
if (cI!=-1) {
    tagName=(String) tag.subSequence(1,cI);
    int numChar=Integer.parseInt((String) tag.subSequence(cI+1,tag.length()-1));
    int end=m.end();
    data = (String) line.subSequence(end,end+numChar);
}
```